# Error while generating sequence in SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2008 Express Edition - how to create a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999448/sql-server-2008-express-edition-how-to-create-a-sequence)

I have written following SQL query to create a sequence in SQL Server 2008R2. I don't know why I am getting this kind of error.

**SQL CODE:**

```
Use CRM 
GO 
CREATE SEQUENCE User_Detail_Sequence 
AS 
int START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 NO MAXVALUE 
GO
```

**Error:**

> Msg 343, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Unknown object type 'SEQUENCE' used
>   in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 does not support sequences - that feature is introduced in SQL Server 2012 (Denali).

Raj